JUnit4 use @RunWith(Suite.class) and @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) together
I have a set of Integration Tests which I want to run in suite. As of now all IT have runner annotated @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class).
Also I have used test containers for Postgres and Casandra. My requirement here is that all ITs are using the same Spring context. So, I do not want to re-create spring context for each IT.
Better run them in a suite.

Start Postgres as test container. Run DDL and DML scripts.
Start Casandra as test container. Run DDL and DML scripts.
Instantiate Spring Context before suite.
Run test1 and assert.
Run test2 and assert.
. . . . and so on . . . .
Delete Spring Context.
Drop Casandra test container.
Drop Postgres test container.

What is the way I can use @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) on Suite class instead of test class.
